# How to understand rational homotopy group of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, rational-homotopy-theory

I understand how the rational homotopy group of n-dimensional sphere is computed. But how to understand that the difference between even and odd cases? In other words, what topological property makes the difference appear? Or what does ‘the 3-rd rational homotopy group of 2-sphere is Q’ mean topologically?

Comment: We can guarantee the existence of higher cohomology of $K(\mathbb{Q},2n)$ by the fact that the cup square gives a natural transformation between cohomology with rational coefficients and itself. Since the sphere is a Moore space this implies that when cup square is nontrivial, that dimension the sphere must have higher homotopy groups because otherwise its rationalization would have higher cohomology since it would be an Eilenberg-MacLane space. In the even case it is nontrivial, but in the odd case it is trivial because there is no two torsion elements rationally.